# Forecasting using SVM regression in R

Tags: r, forecasting, svm

I made an SVM regression model in R using e1071 package for forecasting daily electricity demand. My dataset consists of daily weather and energy consumption data from 1/01/14 till 31/12/16. I trained and tested my model. How will I start forecasting from 1/01/17 for next the 30 days

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide some more context to your question, currently it's not clear enough.

For example, why and how did you decide on SVM regression in the first place? Generally speaking, there are more appropriate models for time series, such as exponential smoothing, Holt-Winters, ARIMA, and so on.

For R you might want to try package `forecast`, specifically I can recommend: [Forecasting: principles and practice](https://www.otexts.org/fpp)

A very good book by Hyndman and Athana­sopou­los, with online (free) access.